# JS string counter

Tags: javascript

I want this code to count the number of times that category and message are in the bottom string, regardles of the different id number. The code just gives me the last one.

It is quite messy, sry. Thanks for your help.

Kind regards.

```js
counter = function() {
    var value = $('#text').val();

    if (value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCount').html(0);

        return;
    }

    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var wordCount = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;

};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var obj = {"data" : { 
                 "from": {
                    "category": "cat1",
                    "id": 1,
                    "message": "WIZ1"
                 },
                 "from": {
                    "category": "cat2",
                    "id": 2,
                    "message": "WIZ2"
                 },
                 "from": {
                    "category": "cat3",
                    "id": 3,
                    "message": "WIZ3"
                 },
                 "from": {
                    "category": "cat4",
                    "id": 4,
                    "message": "WIZ3"
                 },
                }
               };
        
    $.each(obj, function() {
      $.each(this, function(name, value) {
        $("#result").append(name + '=' + value.category);
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">Words: <span id="wordCount">0</span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: First you seem to have a problem with `obj.date` you have 4 x `from` being defined as keys in the same object, and also ending the last item with `,` You are also defining `counter` in the global space, maybe you want this but I doubt it.

Comment: @Xotic750 The last `,` is not wrong, at least not according to [ES 5](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5), but it shouldn't be used as it will break scripts in IE before IE 9.

Comment: Correct, I just didn't fully explain why in my comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Each of the items in the JS object have the same key ('from'). 
That's causing each one to overwrite the previous, which is why it's only finding the last one.

```js
{
  "data": {
    "from1": {
      "category": "cat1",
      "id": 1,
      "message": "WIZ1"
    },
    "from2": {
      "category": "cat2",
      "id": 2,
      "message": "WIZ2"
    },
    "from3": {
      "category": "cat3",
      "id": 3,
      "message": "WIZ3"
    },
    "from4": {
      "category": "cat4",
      "id": 4,
      "message": "WIZ3"
    }
  }
}
```

This will allow it to iterate through each item as there will now be four items present.

Comment: The object in the code is not _JSON_ it is a regular _JavaScript Object_. It is true that the syntax of _JSON_ is a subset of a _JavaScript Object_, but you won't call the JavaScript Object JSON. A JSON is actually an exchange format/language.

Comment: It's not [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), it's a [Javascript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_overview) and not to be confused with the [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Comment: Thanks. Edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single object with the "from" property being overwritten 4 times. It looks like what you wanted was to instead have an array, like the example below.

I also changed the code to actually capture the categories and messages, like the description in your post, after the loops those objects will have the count by message and count by category.

```js
counter = function() {
    var value = $('#text').val();

    if (value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCount').html(0);

        return;
    }

    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var wordCount = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;

};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var obj = {"data" : [ 
                  {
                    "category": "cat1",
                    "id": 1,
                    "message": "WIZ1"
                 },
                {
                    "category": "cat2",
                    "id": 2,
                    "message": "WIZ2"
                 },
                  {
                    "category": "cat3",
                    "id": 3,
                    "message": "WIZ3"
                 },
                  {
                    "category": "cat4",
                    "id": 4,
                    "message": "WIZ3"
                 },
                ]
               };
     var categories = {};
      var messages = {}
    $.each(obj, function() {
      $.each(this, function(name, value) {
        if (!categories[value.category]) categories[value.category] = 0;
        categories[value.category] += 1;
               if (!messages[value.message]) messages[value.message] = 0;
        messages[value.message] += 1;
        $("#result").append(name + '=' + value.category);
      });
    });
  console.log(categories);
  console.log(messages);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">Words: <span id="wordCount">0</span>
    <br/>
</div>
```